# c++ structs and const

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, struct

ok well i have structure

```
struct balls {
    balls(UINT_PTR const &val) : BALL_ID(val){}
    int Ex;
    int Ey;
    const UINT_PTR BALL_ID;
};
balls ball1(0x1);
```

and i have a switch statement

```
switch(wParam)
        {
        case ball1.BALL_ID:
                if(ball1.Ex<300)
                {
                    ball1.Ex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    KillTimer(hWnd, ball1.BALL_ID);
                }
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
                break;
        case SCORECOUNTER_ID:
                if(life==0)
                {
                    if(scorecounter<1000)
                    {
                        scorecounter+=100;
                        _swprintf(str, _T("Score: %d"), scorecounter);
                        InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _swprintf(level, _T("Level: %d"), 2);
                        InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
```

i get an error thatball1.BALL_ID is not constant the second line should solved this but it didn't any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` labels must be *integral constant expressions* -- they must be evaluable during translation (i.e. at compile). In this case, `BALL_ID` cannot be evaluated at compile-time. Different `ball` objects are allowed to have different `BALL_ID` values, hence the compiler cannot possibly evaluate it during translation. Futher, the `.` (member resolution operator for objects) cannot be used in a case label (i.e. even if you did make `BALL_ID` `static` it wouldn't work for you).

I would hazard a guess that `SCORECOUNTER_ID` is a macro/`static const int` and is hence evaluable by the compiler.

You can use a namespace scope `enum` or `int` to fix this. E.g:

```
struct s {
 s(const int t) : x(t) {}
 const int x;
};

namespace s2 {
 const int val = 42;
}

int main() {
 s ss(4);
 int val = 42;
 switch (val) {
  case s2::val:
  break;
  }
}
```

Comment: ... why yes of course, until and unless the OP needs to stick to the `switch`!

Answer (score 0):

case labels have to be known at compile time (the underlying assumption is that a `switch` is implemented more efficiently than a sequence of ifs knowing the values at compile time, using a jump table for instance).  `const` is needed but not sufficient for that. ball.BALL_ID is something `const` which isn't known at compile time, so can't be a case label.

Answer (score 0):

Not every constant variable of an integral type is a constant expression. The case label of the switch statement requires a constant expression.